# how to resolve this duplicate class in Kotlin when Use two SDK's .aar files which contains same class file?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, code-duplication, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Duplicate class bbota01z.bbota01z.bbota01z.a found in modules jetified-boltsdk-release-3.0.71-runtime.jar (boltsdk-release-3.0.71.aar) and jetified-emv-anet-sdk-runtime.jar (emv-anet-sdk.aar)
Duplicate class bbota01z.bbota01z.bbota01z.b found in modules jetified-boltsdk-release-3.0.71-runtime.jar (boltsdk-release-3.0.71.aar) and jetified-emv-anet-sdk-runtime.jar (emv-anet-sdk.aar)

I have already tried lot's of ways but no luck.any help would be appreciatiable.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below line in **gradle.properties** removed my similar error

```
android.enableR8=false
```

And then do a clean build.

To understand this, you can read the below reference link.

Reference link:
https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-3ds2-android/issues/14#issuecomment-530099303

Comment: no luck  still same error as under:-Type bbota01z.bbota01z.bbota01z.a is defined multiple times:35b676666fbbef88b12cc4267693365\jetified-emv-anet-sdk-runtime\classes.dex, external_libs_dex\release\mergeExtDexRelease\classes.dex

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two dependencies that are already obfuscated and clash class names.
`jetified-boltsdk-release-3.0.71-runtime.jar`
`jetified-emv-anet-sdk-runtime.jar`

You can try to disable obfuscation as suggested on the other answer by Shailesh, but I'd suggest maybe looking for the documentation or support from those libs and see if they provide Proguard/R8 rules to avoid the clash.